How do I disable the ckeditor path in my Liferay 6.2 portal?
We have a web portal running in Liferay 6.2. it seems that there is a page under the following URL: /html/js/editor/ckeditor/editor/filemanager/browser/liferay/frmcreatefolder.html
We're not sure where this page originated (perhaps it was added by a developer who is no longer on the project), but we need to disable it for security reasons, and I haven't been able to figure out how to do that yet.
Can anyone help me to remove or disable this page in Liferay itself (as opposed to suggestions on how to control access using external tools or controls or anything like that)?
I tried checking the portal properties, I searched online for details of ckeditor in liferay, but I haven't found anything that seemed helpful so far.

If you need to do something for security reasons then it's certainly not removing access to a single file, but upgrade your version. Lots of bugs (including security relevant ones) have been fixed. If the file in question wasn't in Liferay's default package, this might point to an issue. Otherwise, you should be able to just delete it from the server. However, if it's used and required by Liferay, you might run into malfunction afterwards.

Unfortunately updating Liferay is not an option right now. You refer to it as a file rather than a page, does that mean it's saved as a file somewhere on the server? I don't want to delete it, but if that's the only solution that I can find then I will HAVE to do it. I haven't been able to find the file, do you know where it is?
